# weird numba behavior when assigning to an array

Tags: numpy, numba

I have a function I'm jitting with @jit(nopython=True).

Inside it has a loop that does a bunch of stuff, calculates a correlation and then assigns that to a preallocated output array.  Both the target array and the correlation have the same type (np.float32), but for some reason the assignment makes the function take 100X as long.

To make things even more strange, if i instead assign a meaningless float np.float32(i*1.01) instead of my correlation value, the function runs at an appropriate speed.

Given that everything is the same type, they should both run at the same speed no?

```
corrs = np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)

for i in range(lb, a.shape[0]):
    #a bunch of calculations happens here

    correl = np.float32(covar/(a_std*b_std))

    testval = np.float32(i*1.01)

    #doing this makes the function take FOREVER
    #corrs[i] = correl

    #but doing this runs very quickly, even though it is also a np.float32
    #corrs[i] = testval
```

here is a runable example.  I added an argument called "assign" that if true will assign what I want to assign, and if false will assign my useless test value.

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def hist_corr_loop(a, b, lb = 1000, assign=True):


flb = np.float32(lb)

a_mu, b_mu = a[0], b[0]


for i in range(1, lb):
    a_mu+=a[i]
    b_mu+=b[i]



a_mu = a_mu/flb
b_mu = b_mu/flb


a_var, b_var = np.float32(0.0), np.float32(0.0)
for i in range(lb):
    a_var += np.square(a[i] - a_mu)
    b_var += np.square(b[i] - b_mu)

a_var = a_var/flb
b_var = b_var/flb


corrs = np.zeros(a.shape[0], dtype=np.float32)


for i in range(lb, a.shape[0]):

    #calculate new means and stdevs
    _a_mu = a_mu
    _b_mu = b_mu

    a_mu = _a_mu + (a[i] - a[i-lb])/flb
    b_mu = _b_mu + (b[i] - b[i-lb])/flb

    a_var += (a[i] - a[i-lb])*(a[i] - a_mu + a[i-lb] - _a_mu)/flb
    b_var += (b[i] - b[i-lb])*(b[i] - b_mu + b[i-lb] - _b_mu)/flb

    a_std = np.sqrt(a_var)#**0.5
    b_std = np.sqrt(b_var)#**0.5

    covar = np.float32(0.0)

    for j in range(i-lb+1,i+1):

        covar += (a[j] - a_mu)*(b[j] - b_mu)

    covar = covar/flb

    correl = np.float32(covar/(a_std*b_std))

    testval = np.float32(i*1.01)

    if assign:
        corrs[i] = correl

    else:
        corrs[i] = testval

return corrs
```

to run:

```
n = 10000000
a = np.random.random(n)
b = np.random.random(n)

%timeit hist_corr_loop(a,b,1000, True)
%timeit hist_corr_loop(a,b, 1000, False)
```

I get

```
%timeit hist_corr_loop(a,b,1000, True)
10.5 s ± 52.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit hist_corr_loop(a,b, 1000, False)
220 ms ± 1.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

10 seconds vs 220 ms.

Comment: Can you please include a complete and runnable example?

Comment: @joshadel done .

Comment: I should also point out that if I remove the @jit flag, both versions run at the same speed.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this behaiviour with (Numba 0.38RC1/Python 3.6). Both take about 13s on my PC. Maybe the jit compiler optimizes away most of the calculation, because it's useless if assign=False)